# How can I make an Android SQLite database that uses my laptop as a server?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I currently have a `DatabaseHelper` class in my code (extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`) which creates a table and inserts values into it. The problem with this however is that my app will store data of various users, which can be accessed by users - so doing it this way means that if (for instance) I registered an account in my app on one device, that account wouldn't exist on any other device (since the database is stored in the operating system itself).

For now, I want to use my laptop as a server for the database so that I will be able to log into the same account using any Android device. I installed sqlite on my desktop but I don't have a GUI or anything with it (and am really unsure how to use it). I already have logic for creating a table / inserting data etc. in code - would it be possible to keep this code but store the data somewhere on my laptop instead?

Here is the current code I have:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Accounts";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "account_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "USERNAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "EMAIL";
public static final String COL_4 = "PASSWORD";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String username, String emailAddress, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase  db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_2, username);
    cv.put(COL_3, emailAddress);
    cv.put(COL_4, password);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    return (result != -1);
}

public int Login(String username,String password)
{
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{username, password};
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        Cursor c = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        c = db.rawQuery("select * from " +  TABLE_NAME + " where username=? and password=?", selectionArgs);
        c.moveToFirst();
        i = c.getCount();
        c.close();
        return i;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

> would it be possible to keep this code but store the data somewhere on my laptop instead?

Not directly. That code is for writing to a local SQLite database using Android's SQLite classes.

SQLite is not a server. The fact that you have SQLite on your notebook is insufficient, as nobody but the person sitting at that notebook can access it. You will need to set up some sort of communications between the Android device and the notebook, such as implementing a Web service on the notebook. The means that you use to talk to that Web service (or whatever) will result in different code.

What you can do is:

- Store the data locally using your existing code, and have some separate synchronization mechanism to transfer that data to your notebook (e.g., via a Web service), or
- Switch to some sort of database that handles such synchronization for you automatically (e.g., Couchbase Mobile)